# do not display prices to users not logged

Tags: product, price, login

You must know how to hide prices to users not logged in, perhaps with a message prompting you to log in.

The theme I use is Universal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s hide prices for guest users everywhere.

Open `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/` 
folder and copy `price.phtml` file to the `app/design/frontend/theme_package/your_theme/template/catalog/product/` 
folder and then Place the following code on top of it:

```
<?php
if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
echo '<span class="login_for_price"><strong>Login to See Price</strong></span><br>';
return;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have used before and has worked

Let’s hide prices for guest users everywhere.

Open app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/ folder and copy price.phtml file to the app/design/frontend/base/template/themeXXX/catalog/product/ folder, where XXX is the number of your theme, and then place the following code on top of it:

```
<?php
if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
echo '<span class="login_for_price"><strong>Login to See Price</strong></span><br>';
return;
}
?>
```

Now we will hide the ‘Add to Cart’ button on category list page. Open /app/design/frontend/default/themeXXX/template/catalog/product/list.phtml file and look for the following code:

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button><br>
<?php else: ?>
<p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and replace it with:

```
<?php
if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
echo '<span class="login_for_details" style="float:left"><strong>Login to Add to Cart</strong></span>';
}
else{
?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button><br>
<?php else: ?>
<p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php    }?>
```

and now save the changes.

Now we will hide the ‘Add to Cart’ button on product detail page. Open app/design/frontend/default/themeXXX/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml file.
Add the following code on top of it:

```
<?php
if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
echo '<span class="login_for_details" style="float:left"><strong>Login to Add to Cart</strong></span>';
return;<
}
?>
```

and save changes.

In order to hide the ‘Add to Cart’ button on compare page page, open /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/compare/list.phtml file and copy it to /app/design/frontend/default/themeXXX/template/catalog/product/compare/ folder.
Open it and look for the following code:

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button><br>
<?php else: ?>
<p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and replace it with:

```
<?php
if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
echo '<span class="login_for_details" style="float:left"><strong>Login to Add to Cart</strong></span>';
}
else{
?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button><br>
<?php else: ?>
<p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php    }?>
```

and save changes.

In order to hide the ‘Add to Cart’ button on Specials page, open /app/design/frontend/default/themeXXX/template/catalog/product/widget/sale/sale_default_list.phtml file and look for the following code:

```
<?php
if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
echo '<span class="login_for_details" style="float:left"><strong>Login to Add to Cart</strong></span>';
}
else{
?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button><br>
<?php else: ?>
<p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php    }?>
```

and save changes.

In order to hide the ‘Add to Cart’ button for for new products, open /app/design/frontend/default/themeXXX/template/catalog/product/new.phtml file and look for the following code:

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button><br>
<?php else: ?>
<p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and replace it with:

```
<?php
if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
echo '<span class="login_for_details" style="float:left"><strong>Login to Add to Cart</strong></span>';
}
else{
?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button><br>
<?php else: ?>
<p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php    }?>
```

and save changes.

I have used this tutorial from this website and it has worked before " http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-hide-prices-and-add-to-cart-button-for-non-logged-in-visitors.html#gref "

Answer (score 0):

In your theme product list file **app/design/frontend/Your-Package/Your-Theme/catalog/product/list.phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```

chnage to:

```
<?php if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){ ?>
  <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
<?php }else{ ?>
    <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>customer/account/login">Login to See Price</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Product View page: **app/design/frontend/Your-Package/Your-Theme/catalog/product/view.phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
```

changed to:

```
<?php if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){ ?>
    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
<?php }else{ ?>
        <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>customer/account/login">Login to See Price</a>
<?php } ?>
```